# Debugging classic ASP - simple way to dump locals to a file in multiple places?

Tags: debugging, asp-classic

I'm dealing with a bunch of spaghetti in a classic ASP site. I'm trying to figure out what I need for a particular object construct, but am having a lot of trouble because of the number of variables that are used which have (for all practical purposes) global scope. Walking through with the VS debugger isn't getting me very far because there are a lot of state changes and database lookups happening all over the place.

What I'd like to do is create some kind of debug utility to dump all variables in local scope into a file, and be able to call that from several different places in the code so that I can simply compare values to understand the necessary state changes.

It's a simple enough problem to write data out to a file, but there are *so many* local vars in play, and I'm not sure what are just UI, what are just business data and what are actually controlling flow that I don't yet know what I want to grab.

So that's the problem--the question is:

Is there a built-in way (or a tool of some sort) that will allow me to make a simple call to dump all local variables to some sort of output as name/value pairs or something similar?

Comment: Is this helpful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299986

Comment: @rene - I'd come across that page, but hadn't fully read it; on my first glance, it looked like a pointless explanation of how to create a custom object to write developer-defined data. I didn't see the section where it was calling methods to get session and request data and the like. That might be what I need. I'll see if it works out and post my solution (if any) as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @rene - on further investigation, I'm not sure it helps much. None of the collections it uses seem to be what I need.